# Is there a string method that checks for an exact string of characters and not just for the string to include a set of characters?

Tags: ruby, string, csv, methods

So, I've got a .CSV that I'm trying to parse through. I've managed to do what I wanted: find a specific value in one column and then print out the whole row that value is in. However, I've run into a problem as I can’t find a string method that’ll check for the exact string of characters, and my CSV has values that partially repeat (the list doesn’t make a lot of sense, it’s just to make it simpler):

```
Name, Age
Michael Smith, 40
John Smith, 22
Smith, 33
```

My code looks like this:

```
  def find_row_in_csv(file_path, column_name, search_value)
    CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: true, col_sep: ';').find do |row|
      row[column_name].include?(search_value)
    end
  end
```

If my search value is “Smith”, the printed row is

```
Michael Smith, 40
```

I’m guessing because it’s the first one to include Smith. The thing is, I’m actually trying to print the “Smith, 33” row.

TL;DR: any string methods that’ll check for the exact string of characters?

Comment: row[column_name] == search_value

Comment: thx bro now i feel dumb

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you compare equality with `==` see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-3D-3D  so what you probably want is:

```
  def find_row_in_csv(file_path, column_name, search_value)
    CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: true, col_sep: ';').find do |row|
      row[column_name] == search_value
    end
  end
```